# tiled map editor is rendering on top of everything else in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, tile

I began to use the tiled map editor as an editor for my new game. (it's a platformer). So I created the tiled map and saved it as a .tmx file. the map is VERY simple and I only used it to test it out. In my code I just had a pentagon rendering on the screen as 'the player' object. When I added in the map with this code:

```
package com.thechief.platformer.states;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.thechief.platformer.Gradual;
import com.thechief.platformer.entities.Player;
import com.thechief.platformer.textures.TextureManager;

public class GameState extends State {

    public static final float GRAVITY = 15f;

    private Player player;

    private TmxMapLoader maploader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        setUp();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, Gradual.WIDTH, Gradual.HEIGHT);

        player = new Player(new Vector2(camera.position.x, camera.position.y));

        maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = maploader.load("map.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        player.update(dt);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        sb.begin();

        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();

        player.render(sb);

        sb.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        renderer.dispose();
        map.dispose();
    }

}
```

the map renders, but the player doesn't render!
Here is the `Player.java` class:

```
package com.thechief.platformer.entities;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.thechief.platformer.textures.TextureManager;

public class Player extends Entity {

    private float spd = 4;

    private float velX = 0, velY = 0;

    public Player(Vector2 pos) {
        super(TextureManager.pentagon, pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) {
            pos.x += spd;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {
            pos.x -= spd;
        }


        pos.x += velX;
        pos.y += velY;
    }

}
```

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong in the code?
Or is there something wrong with the player class? I don't think so because even if I replace `player.render(sb);` with `sb.draw(TextureManager.pentagon, x, y)` it still doesn't render.
Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you doing player.render(sb)? Isn't it missing?

Comment: And where is the render method of the player?

Comment: oops! I accidentally did that for debugging! (it still doesn't work with the render method)

Comment: most of  your code are abstract like `State` and `Entity` class or even `render()` of `Player` ?

Comment: yes. update(float dt) and render(sb) are in the state and entity classes. they are abstract. Oh sorry the render method in the entity class is not abstract. it is just executing `sb.draw(texture, pos.x, pos.y, width, height);`

Comment: Have you tried different player positions? Have you tried using a Sprite instead of drawing the texture directly? Look, something like this https://github.com/jmromeroes/colors-game/blob/master/core/src/com/mygdx/colors/states/EntityState.java